# How to create axios plugin in Vue 3 composition api

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using Vue 3 composition api and typescript .

I want to make Axios plugin to use in my project .

this is my code

**plugins/axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
})
export default {
    install: (app, options) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$axios={ ...axiosInstance }
    }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

import axiosPlugin from '@/plugins/axios.js'


import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(axiosPlugin, {})

app.mount('#app')
```

**my component**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { $axios } from 'vue'
```

But I have **error** in last code section

**Module '"vue"' has no exported member '$axios'.ts(2305)**

[image]

maybe something is wrong in declaring plugin for axios

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your axios plugin is not exposed in the Vue library, so importing is not going to work. Your plugin is hooked to the Vue instance. In Vue 2 (or options API) you could use `this` keyword but in the setup method you need to use `getCurrentInstance`. Try this

```js
<script setup lang='ts'>
    import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

    const app = getCurrentInstance()
    const axios = app.appContext.config.globalProperties.$axios
</script>
```

Alternatively you can use provide/inject methods.
In your main.ts

```js
app.provide('axios', axiosInstance);
```

In your component

```js
import { inject } from 'vue';
const axios = inject('axios');
```

Comment: i think you meant add app.provide('axios', axiosInstance); in plugin
am I right ?

Comment: yeah, depends on how you see it, check out this link: https://skirtles-code.github.io/vue-examples/patterns/global-properties.html#application-level-provide-inject

Comment: Bur i have type script error in component for axios.get('/')
it said "Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)"
can you help with that ?